# Python - How to declare common features to a class so that they consume memory only once

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I have a Python class where I need to use some mapping data with size ~300M while processing. This process is to be run using multiple Python workers. As the data won't be changing but the implementation might during the processing, I'm looking for some way to persist this data for every worker using a common source. In other words, I want an implementation where this data doesn't consume memory for every other instance, all workers should be able to use the mapping without creating/using another copy of the same.
Here is a list of implementations I've already tried (or already ruled out) -

1. Add a  `@classmethod` & run each worker with 1 instance of the class.
2. Using global variable.
3. Using variables in ABC.
4. Using LRU functool.
5. Using Redis.

Though, I've tried the above categories of implementation, I might have missed using them in a right way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wholeheartedly recommend option #5 . I use Redis as broker, result backend, and caching. It is made for this kind of stuff anyway, and if you use Redis cluster you also have high-availability too.

Comment: My current implementation uses Redis. But I'm not sure how can I load data once in the memory & make every worker utilize the same instance of data. No worker is modifying the data, hence I want to avoid duplicity of this read-only data. Also I don't want to query each data point separately as this will require more than a million queries, & doing that won't be optimal IMO.

Comment: "More than million" is nothing as these are all very simple, common, "key" searches. Give it a try and try some other alternative if you find this way is suboptimal. KISS principle. :)